# How to add correct hijri date in android application with location based?

Tags: java, android, date, hijri

I want to add [Hijri (Islamic calendar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) date in my project. How can I get current correct date?

Comment: I think its duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728744/converting-gregorian-to-hijri-date

Comment: And apart from being a duplicate, it is unclear, too broad, and off-topic because it's asking to recommend a library. Take your pick and vote to close. I'm still wondering what "location based" means in the context of date conversion...

Comment: i think this is a valid question with no duplication at all..kindly answer this.

Comment: This is a valid question. Because there are not many clear resources or guideline on the internet to build and get location-based Hijri date time.