# How to convert date from Arabic to normal number format like 05/03/2017?

Tags: java, android, date, date-formatting

In my android application I was sending a date in the format 05/03/2017 in a web service to get response. Now if I change my phone's language to Arabic the date is being sent in Arabic. So how should I convert a date in Arabic to a format like 05/03/2017 ?

Comment: Please provide some code of how you are fetching the date

Comment: how is the arabic format? give us an example!!! How do you get it from webservice?

Comment: this link should be helpfull. [convert date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614504/wrong-in-converting-from-gregorian-to-hijri-date-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I have got the solution.

I have a string variable currentFormattedDate which has date in Arabic. Now I had to convert this to MM/dd/yyyy in English before sending it in Web Service.

So this is what I did:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(currentFormattedDate);
SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.US);
finalDate = finalDateFormat.format(date);
```

I first converted the Arabic string date to Date object, then converted it to the format I need with Locale as US,as I need in English. Now I passed this finalDate and got the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Locale.ROOT when you create the arguments for an API call. For example,

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Message you send should be the format of String,right?
So, it won't occur any problem whether you change your phone's language.

Comment: Yes, but no data is returned by the server as they are not handling it. So I need to convert it into English format.

Comment: So,I think, that could be the problem of the format you got different from the web needed, try to use "Locale.Root" or "Locale.getDefault()" as the param.