# Android Hijri Calendar Arabic format not working correctly?

Tags: android, calendar, arabic, hijri

I want to convert the Gregorian calendar into Hijri calendar in Arabic letters.
Could please guide me?

```
void HijriCalender() {
    UmmalquraCalendar now = new UmmalquraCalendar();

    HijriDatePickerDialog dpd = HijriDatePickerDialog.newInstance(
        Volunteer.this,
        now.get(UmmalquraCalendar.YEAR),
        now.get(UmmalquraCalendar.MONTH),
        now.get(UmmalquraCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );

    locale = new Locale("ar", "AE");

    dpd.setLocale(locale);
    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "HijriDatePickerDialog");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuLxI.png)

This is My Current output

Comment: You can use Joda Time. Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728744/converting-gregorian-to-hijri-date

Comment: @StavroXhardha No, Joda Time is unusable because it does not contain the umalqura calendar (which the OP obviously talks about). The same with ThreetenBP.

Comment: Hmm habibi , have you ever came across this ? You could use it and build your own data there . 

https://aladhan.com/islamic-calendar-api

Comment: @StavroXhardha The website you cites seems to use a hijri converter from layth a. ibraheem. And this man seems to use an algorithmic version so it is not the umalqura calendar again. Anyway, the question of the OP is rather about formatting.

Comment: Can you please tell us where do you get the class "HijriDatePickerDialog" from? I think its API has to offer any access to styling / formatting. If not then you have to design your own date picker or use another one.